# VBA - variable gets ComboBox value else gets TextBox value error

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am writing a VBA code that is opened from a UserForm, which includes 2 ComboBoxes and 2 TextBoxes to form a 2D matrix by user's choice.

What I'm trying to do is, have a variable get the combobox value (one variable for each combobox) and if the selection is null, then the variables get the value of the textboxes.
I've googled the expression I need to use for that and stumbled upon ***IsNull***, but the code doesn't work. What I tried was:

```
If IsNull(Matrix_Size_1.value) = False And IsNull(Matrix_Size_2.value) = False Then
    lWidth = Matrix_Size_1.value
    lHeight = Matrix_Size_2.value

ElseIf IsNull(Matrix_Size_1.value) = True And IsNull(Matrix_Size_2.value) = True Then
    lWidth = Matrix_Hand_1.value
    lHeight = Matrix_Hand_2.value
End If
```

Of course I also have to filter more plausible situations as: if one combobox is empty then msgbox, if everything is empty then msgbox but I'll handle it once I'll understand why my code doesn't work.

But the error I get if I DO NOT choose anything from the comboboxes is ***Type mismatch*** even though the *If* code has an option for both of the comboboxes to be empty.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: you might find it easier to use the `ListIndex` Property from the combobox control. If i recall, if ListIndex = -1 then the box has had no value selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Comboboxes `.Style` property is set as `fmStyleDropDownList` then use this

```
If Matrix_Size_1.ListIndex = -1 And Matrix_Size_2.ListIndex = -1 Then
```

If Comboboxes `.Style` property is set as `fmStyleDropDownCombo` then use this

```
If Len(Trim(Matrix_Size_1.Value)) = 0 And Len(Trim(Matrix_Size_2.Value)) = 0 Then
```

You can check the `Style` property in the design mode by right clicking on the combobox and clicking on properties.

**Edit**

From the comments, I have understood that you actually want this

```
Dim lWidth  As Single, lHeight  As Single

If Len(Trim(Matrix_Size_1.Value)) = 0 And Len(Trim(Matrix_Size_2.Value)) = 0 Then
    lWidth = Val(Matrix_Hand_1.Value) '<~~> Val will take care of mismatch caused by empty boxes
    lHeight = Val(Matrix_Hand_2.Value)
Else
    lWidth = Val(Matrix_Size_1.Value)
    lHeight = Val(Matrix_Size_2.Value)
End If
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, even if I fill both of the textboxes and the variables should get their values. My varaibles are Single dimmed, maybe it's the problem?

Comment: What doesn't work? How have you declared `lWidth` and `lHeight`. `As Single`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout you beat me to it :)

Comment: @ShaiRado: Thank God for that ;)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout I have everything dimmed, if I don't use any restrictions on the user's choice the code works, the problems started when I wrote this code

Comment: @vbmolec: So you get an error when the combo's are empty and the textbox is not?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout exactly. I have values typed in both of the textboxes and nothing is selected in the comboboxes, and I get a type mismatch

Comment: @vbmolec Ok what is the value stored in textbox?

Comment: @vbmolec: If they are blank as well then change `lWidth = Matrix_Hand_1.Value` to `lWidth = Val(Matrix_Hand_1.Value)` and `lHeight = Matrix_Hand_2.Value` to `lHeight = Val(Matrix_Hand_2.Value)`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout the values are numbers between 5-1000 (user's choice) so once I have both of the variables declared as single, they should get the values in the textboxes. If I just choose a number from the combobox list with no restrictions it works, that's what I don't get...

Comment: @vbmolec: further to my comment above, see the edit that I made in my answer. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Thank you! now it works, but I just don't understand what the problem is with my code? For me it seems pretty logic, maybe if you can divulge about it so I'll get to the bottom of it next time myself

Comment: @vbmolec: The clue is in the comment in the code above ;) You have declared `lWidth` and `lHeight` as `Single` but are trying to store a `String` in it. An empty textbox return an empty string :)

Comment: Ok, I would've never figured it out myself how to type it correctly. Again, thank you, much appreciated.